# a:hover not working

Tags: html, css, hover

**HTML**

```
 <table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td width="90%"></td>
    <td><a href="#" id="logout"><strong>Logout</strong></a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#logout {
color:#BBB;
}

a:hover {
color:#FFF;
}
```

Though the color of logout appears to be what is given in the css , the color doesn't change when i place my mouse over the link *(to white)* . What is the reason ?

I must tell there are other css files that tend to change the color of the link when the mouse is placed over them and they work fine.

Comment: [Layout tables](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)? [Links to logout](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1)? Oh dear.

Comment: @Quentin: Nothing wrong with logout links, IMHO.  And sometimes using tables instead of 'pure' tableless css for layout can actually spare you endless heartache.  In my experience.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An id selector (`#logout`) is more specific then a type selector (`a`) plus a pseudo-class (`:hover`), so your first ruleset will always [win the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

Use `#logout:hover` instead.

Comment: i haven't understood your answer though the problem is solved. can you please explain clearly

Answer (score 2):

**Simplifying:**

You have two CSS rules that apply to this anchor.

Both rules change the color.

Only one rule can apply; only one color can be chosen.

The browser has to choose between the rule based on an ID (`#logout`) and a rule based on the element type (`<a>`).

The rule based on ID wins in this situation. It is more specific to specify an ID than to specify all elements of a type (anchor).

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow a hierarchy sequence:

Link, Hover, Visited

For example:

> ```
> a:link
> {
>   text-decoration:none;
>   color:#008b45;
> }
>
> a:hover
> {
>   margin-bottom: 3px solid #ff7400;
>   background: white;
> }
>
> a:visited
> {
>   color:#ee9a00;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

HERE U GO! JUST COPY AND PASTA

```css
#logout{
color:#bbb;
}

#logout :hover{
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td width="90%"></td>
    <td><a href="#" id="logout"><strong>Logout</strong></a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use  `Id Selector (#)` than class and other selectors. This will help you to use the `Hover effect` efficiently!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it block or inline-block first.
Like this:

```
#logout {
    display: inline-block
    color:#BBB;
}

a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
}
```